# Ways on how client shares the technical information needed by developers of the project

Tags: project-team, product-management

In a project how is the technical information like server, domain, etc shared by the client to the developers to write their code?

Can the programming team ask for such information from the client?

Comment: Welcom to PMSE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many development teams like to work with a wiki site (e.g. using Confluence) or a content management system (e.g. Sharepoint) or put technical details into items on a product backlog. The development team and other stakeholders should agree a means of communication that suits their way of working.

Software products will typically need at least three distinct environments of technical infrastructure: for development team builds, for acceptance testing and for live production use. You can expect to have multiple host names and connection details to share so an agreed place to put that information is a very good idea.